# Asp.Net Core : Best way to do CRUD operations on 100 tables?

Tags: asp.net-core, crud

I want to perform crud operations on 100 tables as an Api, one way is to create a separate crud on each table.Is there a better way to apply the operation to 100 tables?

Comment: there are third party packages for this: one I could find is [EasyData](https://github.com/KorzhCom/EasyData)

Comment: From your description, I think you can try to Build a Generic CRUD API, You can follow this [article](https://dev.to/guivern/build-a-generic-crud-api-with-asp-net-core-adf) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of your tables are lookup-tables having one of these structure patterns:

- (ID, Name)
- (ID, Name, TypeID)

I think there is a way to move them into only two tables:

- LookupTypes (**ID**, Name)
- LookupData (**ID**, Name, Value, LookupTypeID)

This will minimize your needed model, repository and controller classes.